# Mouse hover over an icon and fetch text of tooltip using pywinauto with python

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I want to hover mouse over a third party icon(for example 'CCleaner' present in system tray in taskbar) and fetch the tooltip text in a variable. In pywinauto, pywinauto.controls.GetTip(tooltip_index), pywinauto.controls.GetTipText(tooltip_index)and pywinauto.GetToolTipsControl() methods are used to get tooltip information. But an error is coming in my code.
Not sure about how to get tooptip_index. A piece of code is as follows:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import Application, taskbar

def click_tray_icon():
    app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer")
    sys_tray = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")

    sys_tray.child_window(title="People").click_input(button='left', double=True)
    s = pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ToolTipsWrapper(sys_tray).texts()
    print(s)
    pywinauto.mouse.move(coords=(1729, 1063))

    pywinauto.controls.GetTip(1)
    pywinauto.controls.GetTipText(1)
```

---

```
AttributeError: module 'pywinauto.controls' has no attribute 'GetTip'
```

Comment: I am working in windows operating system.

Comment: Windows 10? If yes, which RS? Latest Win10 RS5? It's important because shell tray area was changed since Win8.1.

Comment: Also `Application(backend="uia")` assumes you're using UIA backend only. But `common_controls` module is for old `backend="win32"` as well as mentioned functions. Of course these functions are not defined in package folder `pywinauto.controls` inside `__init__.py` but this is only direct root of this exception.

Comment: I would recommend reading the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) first since core concept of pywinauto requires some learning. I'll prepare example for Win10 RS5 few days later.

Comment: Hi Vasily, I am using windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit operating system.

Comment: OS version 1803 ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a chance to make a sample script. But it should work on current master branch (0.6.6 is not released yet). So you have to install pywinauto this way:

```
pip uninstall pywinauto
pip install https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/master.zip
```

The code contains all in-between prints to show the way how I wrote it. Every next step contains copy-pasted `child_window` specification from previous `dump_tree` output. I've just removed unnecessary `auto_id="1504"` filters as I'm not sure these values are the same on all Windows versions.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pywinauto import Desktop

d = Desktop(backend='uia')

# print top level windows
# NOTE: method .windows() is not yet available for Desktop in pywinauto==0.6.5
for w in d.windows():
    print(w)

# print Taskbar subtree
d.Taskbar.dump_tree()

main_tray_toolbar = d.Taskbar.child_window(title="User Promoted Notification Area", control_type="ToolBar")

# print titles of main tray area
for text in main_tray_toolbar.texts():
    print(text)

notification_area_expand = d.Taskbar.child_window(title="Notification Chevron", control_type="Button")
notification_area_expand.invoke()
notification_area = d.window(title="Notification Overflow", control_type="Pane")

# print expanded area subtree
notification_area.dump_tree()

# print hidden icon texts
hidden_toolbar = notification_area.child_window(title="Overflow Notification Area", control_type="ToolBar")
for text in hidden_toolbar.texts():
    print(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.ToolbarWrapper docstring states that,

"Notice that ToolTip controls are children of the **top window**
and not of the toolbar."

this is exactly what I did, just **app.top_window()** and you'll receive your tooltip :D